# applying gradient to color property using css

Tags: css

i have a social media icons section with html.

```
<li class="instagram pull-left"><a target="_blank" href="#"></a></li>
```

this is the style given to it.

```
.instagram a {
    font-size: 22px;
    display: inline-block!important;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    background: #359BED !important;
    color: #fff;
content: "\f16d";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

i want to give background white and the color the gradient color used in instagram .how to do this?
i tried but the gradient is coming as background.not for instagram icon.anybody pls help.

Comment: Can you share html code with us? What library are you using?

Comment: shared html code

Answer (score 1):

try this , you can apply it on background or color depending on what you need

```
    .instagram
        {
            #Your code
             display:inline-block;
  
  /* Create the gradient. */
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #f09433 0%,#e6683c 25%,#dc2743 50%,#cc2366 75%,#bc1888 100%); 
  
  background-size: 100%;

  /* Use the text as a mask for the background. */
  /* This will show the gradient as a text color rather than element bg. */
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; 
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
        }
```

Comment: i want to  give white color as background color and for the content gradient has to apply. <a> tag has to  get white background and color gradient.

Comment: can you share a js fiddle with my code how this works

Comment: Okay you should add theses attribute to the link :

 display:inline-block;
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #f09433 0%,#e6683c 25%,#dc2743 50%,#cc2366 75%,#bc1888 100%);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; 
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;